# How to call an async method safely (from deadlock) in .NET 4.0 web app?

Tags: async-await

I can do something like `service.GetLocaton(111).Result`, but that may deadlock,
I tried

`Task.Factory.StartNew
(async () => await service.GetLocaton(),
CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default).Result.Reult`

but that doesn't look correct.

Comment: `var result = await service.GetLocation(111);` Do not use workarounds, make all involved methods asynchronous or stay synchronous. There are no "sometimes" you are asynchronous or not. Any workarounds are waste of resources and source of confusion in your code base.

Comment: I think `async-await` is available only from 4.5 upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Task.Run(() => ...).Result`. Note, that it is preferred to either use async/await all the way or to stay fully synchronous. But sometimes you need a workaround and the code that I show here is always safe (even in ASP.NET for example).

Without `Task.Run` you can write:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
 async () => await service.GetLocaton(),
 CancellationToken.None,
 TaskCreationOptions.None,
 TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap().Result
```

The important point is that `service.GetLocaton()` is called on a thread that has no `SynchronizationContext` set.

Comment: `Task.Run` is not available in .NET 4.0